# How to prevent BouncingScrollPhysics from bouncing when it reach the end of a CustomScrollView?

Tags: flutter, customscrollview

I want BouncingScrollPhysics at the start and at end of a ScrollView I would like to remove that effect. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Use scrollController and add scollListener to it, and when you reach bottom you would change the state of the Bouncing Effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `physics` on `CustomScrollView` to whatever fits your need this way:

```
new CustomScrollView(
  physics: new ClampingScrollPhysics(),
  ...
);
```

For example you can use `ClampingScrollPhysics`, which will stop at the end of the scroll with nothing else.

Comment: but i want Bouncingscrollphysics at the start

Comment: @Miyad, looks like you have to implement your custom Physics, which behave like Bouncing at the start and Clamping at the end.